# excision in algebraic de Rham cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Hi friends,

I'm reading the notes by Kedlaya "p-adic cohomology from theory to practice", available here

http://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/~barsky/pieces-jointes/kedlaya-aws2007-notes-p-adic-cohom-11mar-290507.pdf

In Remark 1.3.7 on page 6 he says that if $X$ is a smooth algebraic variety over a field $k \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $Z$ is a smooth subvariety of pure codimension $d$, then there exists a excision sequence in algebraic de Rham cohomology

$$
\cdots \to H^{i−2d}_{dR}(Z) \to H^i_{dR}(X) \to H^i_{dR}(X-Z)\to H^{i−2d+1}_{dR}(Z) \to \cdots $$

**Question 1**: I was completely unable to find a reference for this. Can anyone provide a reference?

**Question 2**: I guess one also has an excision sequence of the same form in the singular cohomology of $X(\mathbb{C})$ seen as a complex variety. Are both sequence compatible by the isomorphism period?

**Question 3:** Is it possible to get rid of the shift by codimension by considering the compact support cohomology of $X-Z$?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You should find the answers to your questions in Hartshorne's article 
"On the de Rham cohomology of algebraic varieties", esp. p. 40, p. 47, p. 50.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the comment above, a brief proof can be found in Proposition 2.2.8 of [Abbott-Kedlaya-Roe](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0601508.pdf), a published paper which is one of the main sources for the notes.