# Leray spectral sequence of the inclusion of an open subvariety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, spectral-sequences

Let $X$ be a smooth variety over a field $k \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $Z$ a smooth subvariety. Let $U=X-Z$. I'm trying to understand what information do the Leray spectral sequences attached to the inclusions

$j: U(\mathbb{C}) \hookrightarrow X(\mathbb{C})$

and

$i: Z(\mathbb{C}) \hookrightarrow X(\mathbb{C})$

provide. More precisely, if $F$ is a sheaf on $U$ one has a spectral sequence

$
E_2^{p,q}:=H^p(X, R^q j_\ast F) \Longrightarrow H^{p+q}(U, F)$

Is there a long exact sequence associated to it such that, when $F$ is the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Q}$, gives something like excision for usual cohomology?

Comment: Yup, the sequence you get is the one written here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/121910/excision-in-algebraic-de-rham-cohomology
by another anonymous user. 

Comment: @Donu: I cannot see the connection, perhaps you can elaborate this in an answer?

Comment: Marthin, see below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few more details:
Suppose that $F=\mathbb{Q}_X$. 
In this case, 
$$
R^qj_*F = 
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{Q}_X & \text{if $q=0$}\\
\mathbb{Q}_Z & \text{if $q= 2 c-1$, $c=codim(Z)$}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} 
$$
To see this, first note that the computation is local, so we may replace the pair $(X,Z)$ by $(\mathbb{C}^n, \mathbb{C}^{n-c})$ using the implicit function theorem. After this, it should be easy. With this calculation the $E_2$ term of Leray is concentrated along two lines, and it is not hard to see that it reduces to the above "localization" sequence given in [excision in algebraic de Rham cohomology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121910/)

Notes: Sorry, I had a typo in the formula yesterday. If $Z$ is smooth but not pure dimensional, then  $R^qj_*F|_{Z_i}= \mathbb{Q}_{Z_i}$ where $q=2c_i-1$ for each component. The final result will be a bit more cumbersome to state. Some related calculations occur
in Deligne's Theorie de Hodge I, II.

Comment: Thanks, Donu! Your answer is very useful. I'm not very familiar with tubular neighbourhoods. Could you give some references?

Comment: Another question: what happens if $Z$ is not of pure dimension? Do you have the same $R^qj_\astF=\mathbb{Q}_{Z_i}$ if $q=q2c_i$ for each irreducible component?

Answer (score 2):

For a closed immersion $i : Z \hookrightarrow X$ of schemes the spectral sequence is degenerate and becomes the elementary isomorphism $H^p(X,i_* F) \cong H^p(Z,F)$.

For a morphism $j : U \hookrightarrow X$ of schemes the five term exact sequence associated to the spectral sequence becomes

$0 \to H^1(X,j_* F) \to H^1(U,F) \to \Gamma(X,R^1 j_* F) \to H^2(X,j_* F) \to H^2(U,F).$

In general this cannot be simplified, even if $j$ is an open immersion. But this is useful, for example for the computation of the etale cohomology of $\mu_n$ and $\mathbb{G}_m$ on a curve $X$, where $j$ is the inclusion of the generic point (see Chapter 10 in Tamme's book on etale cohomology).